# Compilation conditional on found libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

My project depends on several libraries, neither of which is essential to it's operation. I feel this means it is time to stop using `target_link_libraries( proj REQUIRED libA libB)` and start managing to compile with reduced functionality without some of the libraries.

One way I can think of of managing my code is to surround whole headers and sources with `#ifdef libA_FOUND`. Is there a better solution?

Comment: How does a project depend on a library that is not essential to its' operation?

Comment: @nicomp it helps provide optional features.